# Angular and MEAN.js $scope attributes are undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean-stack

I am currently developing a little app with Angular and MEAN.js.
I would like to plot a D3 chart with some real data coming from the model.
To do so, I would have to read from the $scope.campaign variable and initialize the $scope.dataBarChart with the data from $scope.campaign.tokens that is an array.

```
// Find existing Campaign
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.campaign = Campaigns.get({ 
        campaignId: $stateParams.campaignId
    });

    $scope.dataBarChart = [
        {
        'key': 'Token Requested',
        'values': [['10.10.2014', 550000], ['11.10.2014',300000]]
        }, {
        'key': 'Token Consumed',
        'values': [['10.10.2014', 250000], ['11.10.2014',200000]]
        }
    ];
};
```

When I try to log the value of $scope.campaign, I get all the data that I need. Unfortunately, when I try to access the $scope.campaign.tokens, I get an error like impossible to access tokens from undefined value. Basically, it seems that there is no data, but I know from the log that is not like this.

The complete code is simply the same, but with a console.log line

```
// Find existing Campaign
$scope.findOne = function() {
$scope.campaign = Campaigns.get({ 
   campaignId: $stateParams.campaignId
});

console.log($scope.campaign)

$scope.dataBarChart = [{
   'key': 'Token Requested',
   'values': [['10.10.2014', 550000], ['11.10.2014',300000]]
   }, {
   'key': 'Token Consumed',
   'values': [['10.10.2014', 250000], ['11.10.2014',200000]]
}];
};
```

The console.log shows the right content, but when I try to use it $scope.campaign.tokens, it says undefined.

Anyone suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Show us the code where you are logging scope.campaign and where you are accessing it.

Comment: What does Campaigns.get return?

Comment: Double check your DI asap!

Comment: @NoahMatisoff what do I have to check?

Comment: Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$scope.campaign.$promise.then(function(data) {
   console.log(data.tokens)
});
```